# How do a button on a listview (list view with button) could be implemented (as in the screenshot given)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to create an app with a button in the list view as in the below picture. I should be able to click and navigate to another page by clicking the list item and I should be able to use the button (or a switch) in the listview. I don't know whether it is a list view itself in the first hand.

Any help with some sample code is greatly appreciated. [image: Below is A screenshot of sample app]

Comment: For that you have create custom list item view xml.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you please give more details about how do I implement this. What customization I have to do and how? Please give some pseudo code. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//try this
hi this demo list item view you have modify as per requirement and also hide-show inner view like switch button show on some cases..

**listitem.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:text="Power Saving"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:checked="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inflate this view in your list and you will get what you want.


 <LinearLayout
android:layout_weight="3"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Imageview1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/img"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Textview1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:text="your text"
    android:ellipsize="end"/>

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:checked="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```